# the use of AJAX with nodejs

Tags: node.js, jquery

I'm running a linux server with nginx and node. I'm currently developing a small web app and I'm using nodejs to server up the files since it's only one html page, and some javascript files.

The problem that I'm having is within one of my javascript files i use multiple calls to $.getScript() which if I read correctly is just a shorthand ajax call.

The Nodejs server seems to choke on this every time.

Is there a dependency I need to use or module I can install to help out with this? Or maybe it's just a specific request I'm not accounting for?

This might be a dumb question but I'm still a noob. :P

Comment: There's nowhere near enough information to diagnose this.  Error messages?  Relevant code samples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$.getScript() will just try and do an HTTP GET in order to fetch the script from the webserver. If you're using Express, make sure it is configured to statically serve the Javascript files. For example, if you were trying to do $.getScript("dojo/dojo.js") to load the script /var/www/dojo/dojo.js, make sure you had something like the following in your nodejs code,

```
var app = express.createServer();

app.configure(function () { 
     app.use(app.router);
     app.use(express.static('/var/log/www'));
});
```

Comment: okay, ya. It was just me being a noob. I was using local url strings in my $.getscript() requests.